# Why does drupal use Like rather than Equal operator in db_select()

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

```
function user_account_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
    ...
    db_select('users')->fields('users', array('uid'))->condition('uid', $account->uid, '<>')->condition('name', db_like($form_state['values']['name']), 'LIKE')->range(0, 1)->execute()->fetchField()
    ...
}
```

this code `condition('name', db_like($form_state['values']['name']), 'LIKE')` use 'Like' to compare name field, why not use '='?

Comment: 'Like' is used for pattern matching. While '=' operator is used for equating the exact values.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your LIKE statement could include wildcards like "*" and "?", that's why it is using "LIKE" instead of "="

By the way, I just learned that in MySQL both the "=" and LIKE operators are case-insensitive if the table/field has been defined with a collation like utf8_general_ci ("_ci" for "case insensitive"). I always thought that = was sensitive and LIKE was insensitive, but that appears not to be the case (pun intended!).